# Buscar las coincidencias de máximo tamaño con un mínimo de "n" caracteres en diferentes cadenas

Tags: java, string

Tengo un proyecto en el cual tengo que buscar coincidencias de caracteres entre 3 diferentes Strings a partir de 4 caracteres por ejemplo:

```
String cadena1 = "aaattkggl";
String cadena2 = "rrattkmmt";
String cadena3 = "wwattkkllg";
```

como se puede observar entre las 3 cadenas se encuentran los caracteres "attk" y el programa deberia imprimir "attk".

en caso de tener mas de 4 caracteres unidos en las 3 cadenas debería imprimirlos, ejemplo:

```
String cadena1 = "cadenaxyuiop"
String cadena2 = "qwertcadenaxqwert"
String cadena3 = "asdfghcadenax"
```

se deberia imprimir: "cadenax"

gracias a otro usuario pude avanzar con este código:

```
    //Pedir datos al usuario y validarlos
    System.out.print("Ingrese primer cadena: ");
    cadena1 = leer.nextLine();
    if (cadena1.contains("b")||cadena1.contains("j")||cadena1.contains("Ã±")||cadena1.contains("x")||cadena1.contains("z"))
    {
        System.out.println("La cadena contiene caracteres invalidos");
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("\n");
        System.out.print("Ingrese segunda cadena: ");
        cadena2 = leer.nextLine();
        if (cadena2.contains("b")||cadena2.contains("j")||cadena2.contains("ñ")||cadena2.contains("x")||cadena2.contains("z"))
        {
            System.out.println("La cadena contiene caracteres invalidos");
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("\n");
            System.out.print("Ingrese tercer cadena: ");
            cadena3 = leer.nextLine();
            if (cadena3.contains("b")||cadena3.contains("j")||cadena3.contains("ñ")||cadena3.contains("x")||cadena3.contains("z"))
            {
                System.out.println("La cadena contiene caracteres invalidos");
            }

            //dividir la cadena en 4 caracteres y compararlos con las otras cadenas
            else 
            {
                System.out.println("\n***************************************************");
                for (int i=4; i<cadena1.length();i++)
                {
                    String[] partes = cadena1.split("(?<=\\G.{" + i + "})");
                    for (String parte : partes)
                    {
                        if (parte.length() < 4) break;
                        if(cadena2.contains(parte)&&cadena3.contains(parte))
                        cadenator.add(parte);
                    }
                }
            }

            System.out.println(cadenator);
        }
    }
}
```

pero no logro que pueda imprimir el resultado esperado con cualquier cadena, como la del primer ejemplo.

de igual manera debería poder imprimir varias coincidencias en el caso de haberlas, ejemplo:

```
String cadena1 = "holaxxxxxxamigo";
String cadena2 = "amigottttttttthola";
String cadena3 = "ggggggggholagamigo";
```

esto debería imprimir "hola" - "amigo"

Si alguien podría ayudarme, lo agradecería muchísimo.